# Saving Converted OCRed File using ABBYY in commandLine

Tags: command-line, ocr, command-prompt, abbyy

Hi want to integrate ABBYY Fine reader to my custom application
i use the commandline `FineCMD.exe MyDocument /lang french /send MsWord`

It does the OCR process by converting my document and pass it to Msword. I want the FineCMD to Save the converted OCRed word document to a folder How To handle that using commandline argument?

Iam USING **ABBYY Fine Reader 12** on **Windows 10**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABBYY FineReader does not provide command line interface for saving the result from scripting or for batch processing.  FineReader is a desktop application intended for UI-driven use and not intended for black-box integration.  The fitting ABBYY package for that task is Recognition Server or Engine SDK for true development, which btw has CLEI precompiled sample.

(Source: I am a former ABBYY dev/support tech and currently an independent ABBYY technology integrator)

Comment: Are there VBA tools available with ABBYY or any documentation?