# Using FineReader in VBA

Tags: vba, ocr, abbyy

In my workplace we get a lot of invoices which we process using Abbyy 11.  The images are basically tables with financial data.  I have some understanding of VBA and have been using it to gain time.  I googled a lot but could not find any help on how to use FineReader in VBA.  I have seen that the reference box has it and if I use CreateObject("FineReader.Application"), it does create an instance of finereader but after that I am stuck. I have searched a lot but found nothing useful.  Looking for some help here.

Comment: You might want to look at the Abbyy website and their online help for that purpose: http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/ There is even an API Reference and some code snippets for some programming languages (although it does not seem that it can be called upon from VBA directly).

Comment: The above-mentioned link is for an online SDK for developers.  That documentation is different than the FineReader application.

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY FineReader Professional & Corporate Edition are a desktop application, designed to be used interactively by user input, with little-to-none integration and automation capabilities.  From API you can invoke it, open images, initiate recognition.  The rest of the process needs to be finished manually.

I answered a similar question about FineReader automation here: [Saving Converted OCRed File using ABBYY in commandLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351634/saving-converted-ocred-file-using-abbyy-in-commandline/34427396#34427396)

On another subject, there are much more automated tools for consistent table capture and especially for Invoice capture.  If you are processing a few, then FineReader can work via manual processing.  If you are processing a few thousand Invoices, then I would use a better-suited package.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time on this.. I have been hovering on this for some time but with no luck.. The information you provided is helpful.. SDK is something that is too complicated for me at this point.. We are using ABBYY and it works well for us.. But if there are other software available that can be used from VBA then I would like to know..